# Unable to find if user login is correct

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, pdo

I have a problem with my PHP & PDO login form. In fact, the script cannot find that the user already exists, whereas when I do the SQL command in phpMyAdmin, I get 1. Here is the piece of code in question:

```
$requser = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM userInfo WHERE name = ? AND password = ?");
$requser->execute(array($pseudo, $password));
$userexist = $requser->rowCount(); //ERREUR
```

Here is the entire code [link](https://pastebin.com/PxkDUKJC).

And the result [link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/440540332912934915/664700373172224011/unknown.png):

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes created using PHP's [`password_hash()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), which you can then verify using [`password_verify()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Take a look at this post: [How to use password_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30279321/1839439) and learn more about [bcrypt & password hashing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/1839439)

Answer (score -1):

I've remove my install verification process on the the top of the file. MySQL was busy. ->I've get a buffer error because of two sql commands.